# Digital picture frame with 4k

Tags: displays

I'm looking for a digital picture frame with 4k resolution. What I found are Samsung's "The Frame", but the smallest one is 43".

Does anybody know about a 4k digital picture frame in the 20"-32" range?

Comment: Samsung's "The Frame" is a TV, not a digital picture frame. If you are ok with a TV, why not just purchase a 4K TV or Monitor that is 20"-32"?

Comment: Because of the nice framing of "The Frame". It's wooden. And also it turns automatically on if somebody is in the room. It's just a working solution. Perfect besides the size.